# Is this a good way of reading a binary file full of doubles?

Tags: java, file, binary

I have a list of binary files that I need to read and then, store to a variable. Each file is a collection of a huge number of doubles. The files were saved with a C program with double type in C under linux. Now, I want to read all these files using Java. Is this the fastest approach you can achieve? In my PC it takes 24 seconds to read 10 files (1.5 Mb/files with 194,672 doubles/file) and store them into an array. I was thinking in using some type of buffer but I am not sure if I should leave some bytes from the begging...

```
    int i;
    int num_f = 10;
    int num_d = 194672;

    File folder = new File(route);
    File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();

    float double_list[][] = new float[num_f][num_d];

    for (int file = 0; file < listOfFiles.length; file++) {
        if (listOfFiles[file].isFile()) {
            try{
                br = new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream(listOfFiles[file].getAbsolutePath()));
                //We read all file 
                i = 0;
                while(br.available() > 0) {
                    //I know that float != double but I don't think I will lose a huge precision 
                    //as the double numbers stored are in a region [-5,5] and with this way I reduce 
                    //the amount of memory needed. (float) is not cpu consuming (<1s).
                    double_list[file][i++] = (float) br.readDouble();
                }

                }
            }catch (Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }finally {
                try {
                    //Close file
                    br.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
     }
```

Comment: You should add a [`BufferedInputStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/BufferedInputStream.html) between the `DataInputStream` and the `FileInputStream`. Default buffer size should be good, but you can always experiment if you want to.

Comment: Using `DataInputStream` you cannot control the [endianness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness). If your code doesn't work, it could be for that reason, so you might need to use a [`DoubleBuffer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/DoubleBuffer.html) instead.

Comment: ok so with buferedinputstream now it takes 7s, a reduction of 70%. Nice! Nothing more can be improved? BTW, how can I use DoubleBuffer?

Comment: If your in-memory array was `double`, not `float`, then you could try using `DoubleBuffer` instead, reading 10 blocks of `8 * num_d = 1557376` bytes into a `byte[]`, then use `ByteBuffer.wrap(bytes).asDoubleBuffer().get(double_list[i])`. This block-reading may be faster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I could do it with the help of Andreas and this website (http://pulasthisupun.blogspot.com.es/2016/06/reading-and-writing-binary-files-in.html) (check there for other type formats!). For endianness, the default option is the BIG_ENDIAN code but with that I had nonsense things as infinity numbers. Nonetheless, with LITTLE_ENDIAN i'm getting the correct numbers! Still though I will have to do some test in the future just to be sure that I do not have to let some extra byte from the beginning...

BTW, time spent: 0.160048575s, not bad ;)

```
int i;
int num_f = 10;
int num_d = 194672;

File folder = new File(route);
File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();

float double_list[][] = new float[num_f][num_d];

for (int file = 0; file < listOfFiles.length; file++) {
    if (listOfFiles[file].isFile()) {
        try{
           fc = (FileChannel) Files.newByteChannel(Paths.get(listOfFiles[file].getAbsolutePath()), StandardOpenOption.READ);
           byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate((int)fc.size());
           byteBuffer.order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN);
           fc.read(byteBuffer);
           byteBuffer.flip();

           buffer = byteBuffer.asDoubleBuffer();
           ((DoubleBuffer)buffer).get(double_list[file]);
           byteBuffer.clear();

           fc.close();
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }finally {
            try {
                //Close file
                br.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
 }
```